# Feature Detection of PerformanceNavigationTiming API

Tags: javascript, api, browser, cross-browser

How would I check if [PerformanceNavigationTiming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming) is supported in a given browser via JavaScript?

I already know that its unsupported in Safari and IE, but would like a way to target those browsers via the feature I'm attempting to use not user agent regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PerformanceObserver.supportedEntryTypes.includes("navigation")`.